# Vertical alignment of ShareThis icons

Tags: css, sharethis

When using [ShareThis](http://help.sharethis.com/customization/customization-overview), the icons display below the baseline position. This is not good, especially when adjacent to Facebook and Twitter icons.

I added a `vertical-align` rule to the ShareThis spans and this solved the problem on IE and FF. But Chrome and Safari still have the vert align problem.

[Example page](http://us.conf-dev.masteragenda.com/h/example/conf_session/8096.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `vertical-align:top` for the second `span` with class `stButton` instead the first `span`.