# <span> not remaining inline when using ShareThis

Tags: html, css, tumblr, sharethis

I've had a ShareThis plugin installed on my blog for quite some time now but have only just noticed that not all my 'share icon's' are displaying inline.

I've tried using padding-bottom and margin-bottom but that didn't accomplish what I was hoping.

Would any of you be able to shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Code snippet:

```
<div style= "display: inline; float: left; padding-left: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px;">
<span st_url='{Permalink}' st_title='{Title}' class='st_fblike' displayText='Facebook     Like'></span>
<span st_url='{Permalink}' st_title='{Title}' class='st_twitter' </span>
<span st_url='{Permalink}' st_title='{Title}' class='st_email'></span>
</div>
```

Note, in the preview window, the icons remain inline. Very odd.

Comment: Share This will be adding its own stuff inside these span tags, you need to be trying to override the styling on these if you can.

Comment: Close your span tag: <span st_url='{Permalink}' st_title='{Title}' class='st_twitter' </span>

Answer (score 0):

Replace this CSS class in your script.

```
.stButton {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
margin-right: 3px;
margin-left: 3px;
font-size: 11px;
line-height: 26px;
}
```

As you can see I have changed line-height to 26px and now it can fit correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem using this method: [Vertical alignment of ShareThis icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549235/vertical-alignment-of-sharethis-icons?rq=1)

It's worked although displays oddly in the preview panel.

My next problem is the alignment of the disqus comments. I've tried text-align: right and padding to no avail. I also seem to have lost the line that went across the whole column beforehand... See the image and code below.

```
    <div style="padding-bottom:1px; display: inline-block;">
    <span style="vertical-align: top;"st_url='{Permalink}' st_title='{Title}' class='st_fblike' displayText='Facebook Like'></span>
    <span style="vertical-align: top;" st_url='{Permalink}' st_title='{Title}' class='st_twitter'> </span>
    <span style="vertical-align: top;"st_url='{Permalink}' st_title='{Title}' class='st_email'></span>    

     {block:IfDisqusShortname}<div style= "display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"><a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread" class="comments">{lang:View comments}</a></div>{/block:IfDisqusShortname}
     {/block:Date}
```

[***Link to image!***](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/5351/tempah.jpg)

Comment: If you want to ask another question, create a new question, don't ask it in an answer.